# IsEqual object available in VBScript for the ArrayList classes?

Tags: excel, vbscript, wsh, vba

Please find the below code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim TempArr
Dim ArrListChildDetails :  Set ArrListChildDetails = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

Now I have assigned some Range object to it:

```
ArrListChildDetails = ob3.Cells(ParentMatchRowNum,Width+1).Resize(, UBound(TempArr, 1) + 1)
TempArr=ArrListChildDetails.ToArray()   
ArrListChildDetails .Sort();
```

Now Is it possivle to compare both the array,if their elements are same and same positions and the count also? Means any `IsEql()` available in ArrayList Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution but in most cases sufficient:

```
WScript.Echo Join(ArrListChildDetails.ToArray(),"|") = Join(ArrListChildDetails2.ToArray(),"|")
```

EDIT: some explanation: to compare two ArrayLists (or two arrays), convert to an array and join them together to a string separated by some special character not used in the arrays and then compare the strings, of course this is only usable for one dimensional arrays with valuetypes which can be stringified. If they have the same sumber of elements with the same content the comparison will return -1 (true) and 0 (false) otherwise

Comment: is this return `True` if both are same? During `Matching` will it check all `elements,their positions and total count`?

Comment: could you please tell if it returns "true",when two object will be equal and `false` for the otherwise?

Comment: thanks for accepting, comparing the objects (are the idetifiers refering to the same object) is by the .equals method of the ArrayList class, the solution here is to see if the contents of two ArrayLists are the same

Comment: can you help me here in my below post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030365/i-am-getting-an-error-in-my-vbscript-code-subscript-out-of-range

Comment: really stuck in that post!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, where you got the IsEqual() from, but you can use the ArrayList/Object method .Equals() to determine whether one ArrayList is refered to by another name/variable (cf. VBScript's Is operator).

To check whether the count, the order, and the elements of two different ArrayLists are equal, you'll have to roll your own function. To get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Dim alA  : Set alA  = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim alB  : Set alB  = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim alC  : Set alC  = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim alA2 : Set alA2 = alA

alA.Add "one"
alA.Add "two"

alB.Add "one"
alB.Add "two"

alC.Add "one"
alC.Add "owt"

WScript.Echo "alA: ", Join(AlA.ToArray())
WScript.Echo "alA2:", Join(AlA2.ToArray())
WScript.Echo "alB: ", Join(AlB.ToArray())
WScript.Echo "alC: ", Join(AlC.ToArray())

WScript.Echo "alA.Equals(alA2):", CStr(alA.Equals(alA2))
WScript.Echo "alA.Equals(alB):" , CStr(alA.Equals(alB))
WScript.Echo "alA.Equals(alC):" , CStr(alA.Equals(alC))

WScript.Echo "ALEqual(alA, alA):", CStr(ALEqual(alA, alA))
WScript.Echo "ALEqual(alA, alA2):", CStr(ALEqual(alA, alA2))
WScript.Echo "ALEqual(alA, alB):", CStr(ALEqual(alA, alB))
WScript.Echo "ALEqual(alA, alC):", CStr(ALEqual(alA, alC))

Function ALEqual(alL, alR)
  ALEqual = True
  If alL Is AlR Then Exit Function
  ALEqual = alL.Count = alR.Count
  If ALEqual Then
     Dim i
     For i = 0 To alL.Count - 1
         If alL(i) <> alR(i) Then
            ALEqual = False
            Exit Function
         End If   
     Next
  End If  
End Function
```

output:

```
alA:  one two
alA2: one two
alB:  one two
alC:  one owt
alA.Equals(alA2): Wahr
alA.Equals(alB): Falsch
alA.Equals(alC): Falsch
ALEqual(alA, alA): Wahr
ALEqual(alA, alA2): Wahr
ALEqual(alA, alB): Wahr
ALEqual(alA, alC): Falsch
```